# How to dynamically create threads and restart each of them?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How to dynamically create threads and restart each of them after it done working?

For example, I have List with many computer names defined as class:

```
public class GComputers
{
    private List<string> list;

    public GComputers()
    {
        list = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> GetList()
    {
        lock (list)
        {
            List<string> c_list = list.ToList<string>();
            return c_list;
        }
    }

    public void SetList(List<string> List)
    {
        lock (list)
        {
            list = List.ToList<string>();
        }
    }
    public int GetCount()
    {
        return list.Count();
    }
}
```

In main program I have functions:

1.Takes computer name from class and remove name from list

```
public static string GetPCName()
{
    string pcname = null;
    List<string> gl = adc.GetList();
    foreach (string comp in gl)
    {
        pcname = comp;
        gl.Remove(comp);
        adc.SetList(gl);
        break;
    } // End foreach.
    return pcname;
}
```

2.Do some work with this computer (for example, just show pc name and sleep for 3 sec)

```
public static void DoWork()
{
    string pctocheck = GetPCName();
    Console.WriteLine("PCName: {0}",pctocheck);
    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
}
```

3.Thread Manager that create threads

```
public static void ThreadManager()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(DoWork);
        t.Name = "Thread_" + i;
        t.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} started: ",t.Name);
    }
}
```

And part of main():

```
class Program
{
    static GComputers adc;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        adc = new GComputers();

        ThreadManager();
    }
}
```

This code can only create and start 10 threads at once. How to restart each of them until list of computers have more than 0 items?

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want to do (if you have a collection that is "full" at the beginning and you want to do some work on this collection in many threads, or if you have a collection that receives new data while the old data is being "worked on"), you can use the `Parallel.ForEach` (first case) or the `BlockingCollection<>` (second case), instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: As @xanatos said, TPL would make this a lot easier, but a small side remark on your current code: it is not thread safe: if you lock on the active instance of `list` and change the instance `list` refers to, the active locks will no longer lock the same object and thus new locks can be acquired before the old locks are released. For this sort of implementation it's easier to use some sort of bag or queue, which does the removing for you (e.g. `ConcurrentBag<string>` ). (Although by using `Parellel.ForEach`, you can handle all elements without removing)

Comment: Thanks to @Me.Name! I use this as ThreadMan() function after your answer: `List<String> complist = new List<String>();
complist = adc.GetList();
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = numThreads;
ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.ForEach(complist,options,
            (pcname) =>
                 {
                     DoWork(pcname);
                     namestaken++;
                 });
while (!result.IsCompleted) ;` and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a `ThreadPool`.

*look over here: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx_)*

---

If you want to make your own. Create 10 threads and they will check an `AutoResetEvent`. When you put an item to the workqueue, just trigger the AutoResetEvent. Only one thread will be signaled is allowed to process the workitem.

Comment: I tried to make like on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but my threads didn't restart. Looks like i did not understand how to do this with many threads right

Comment: You should not restart threads. Create a while loop, until your application terminates. Within the while loop let them wait on AutoResetEvents when there is nothing to process. So start the threads on startup. Let them wait on a workitemsqueue. Terminate them when closing.